# How to ensure in C# that the type of an object is equal to this?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, type-conversion, strong-typing

#### Problem

I have the following interface (it can be changed, but just to give the idea):

```
public interface IObj<T>
{
    void Merge(IObj<T> other);
}
```

The problem is with the `Merge` operation. I am not able to find a way to ensure that the parameter passed to the method is of the same type that `this`. For example have a look at the following implementation:

```
public class A<T> : IObj<T>
{
    public void Merge(IObj<T> other)
    {
        var casted = other as A<T>;
        if (casted == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect type.");

        // do the actual stuff
    }
}
```

Any object implementing the interface will always require to be merged with an instance of the same type. Therefore I need to write this boilerplate code to try casting before I do anything.

#### Question

Is it possible to ensure this by contract / interface / anything else?

Comment: you could use generic constraints. or explicitly implement the interface and add an overload.

Comment: You could use `GetType()==other.GetType()`, but that's generally not a good diea.

Comment: You could also add a `TSelf` parameter to the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the @nsinreal solution, I propose you one other level on interface (and an abstract class, to avoid implementing several time the interfaces):

```
public interface IObj<T>
{
    void Merge(IObj<T> other);
}

public interface IObj<T, TImplementor> : IObj<T>
    where TImplementor : class, IObj<T, TImplementor>
{
    void Merge(TImplementor other);
}

public abstract class AObj<T, TImplementor> : IObj<T, TImplementor>
    where TImplementor : class, IObj<T, TImplementor>
{
    public abstract void Merge(TImplementor other);

    void IObj<T>.Merge(IObj<T> other)
    {
        var casted = other as TImplementor;
        if (casted == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect type.");
        Merge(casted);
    }
}

public class A<T> : AObj<T, A<T>>
{
    override public void Merge(A<T> other)
    {
        // do the actual stuff
    }
}

public class B<T> : AObj<T, B<T>>
{
    override public void Merge(B<T> other)
    {
        // do the actual stuff
    }
}
```

Now, for a class called `SpecificObj<T>`, you have both methods:

```
void Merge(IObj<T>)
void Merge(SpecificObj<T>)
```

and you can still use it as an `IObj<T>`

Still not sure that completely answer to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to use [self-referencing generic pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2008/06/12/generics-the-self-referencing-generics-pattern/).
It's often used in fluent builders of inheritable objects.

For your case it should look like this:

```
public interface IObj<T, TSelf> where TSelf : IObj<T, TSelf>
{
    void Merge(TSelf other);
}

class A<T>: IObj<T, A<T>> {
    public void Merge(A<T> alreadyCasted) {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this introduces boilerplate code too (in declaration of class A). But it's nice when you have a lot of method in interface of base class.

As I know, there are no other variants.

Comment: I feel like it would be better to put the constraint on the A<T>. So A<TSelf<T>> : Where TSelf<T>: IObj<T>

Comment: @AlexKrupka can you explain a bit more? Just, I don't see how to class A is propagated into interface (in my case propagation happens with binding TSelf to A<T>). And you are using TSelf<T>. As I know, high-level generics aren't supported in C# (so you can't make TCollection<TItemType> parameter, in LINQ always method accepts IEnumerable<TItemType>)

Comment: @nsinreal Let's assume I then have another implementation of the `IObj<T, TSelf>` interface, let's call it `B<T>: IObj<T, B<T>>`. How could I write the type of a variable explicitly so that I can assign both A or B to it? Is it possible? I simply want to do something like `sometype x = new A<T>()` or `sometype x = new B<T>()`. What would the `sometype` be? Apart from `dynamic` or `object` :D

Comment: Actually you're correct I was thinking of the constraint being on the Inheriting class But here obviously it need to be on the Interface for the  method signature.

Comment: @Randolph Well, I should explain a bit more what happens in terms of semantics. When you are introducing generic TSelf into interface it can be expressed in terms of splitting interface. E.g. IObjForAClass<T>, IObjForBClass<T>. Here is a question for you. What do you expect from line `x.Merge(y)`? E.g. if x is A<T> and y is B<T> then obviously this line shouldn't compile. So, there are no ability to introduce variable that accepts both A and B.

Comment: @Randolph but you could define a generic method like this: `public static void TwiceMerge<T, TSelf>(TSelf obj, TSelf another) where TSelf:IObj<T, TSelf> {
  obj.Merge(another);
  another.Merge(obj);
 }`

Comment: @Randolph But here is another case that should be taked into account. For example, you want have ability to group some `IObj` objects into list and then process them separately. Then you can introduce marker interface `IObj` (without generic constraints) and inherit it from `IObj<T,TSelf>`. `List<IObj>` would be nicer than `List<Object>`, but it's have no compile-time checking